# IBM Maximo File Dialog Box to Create Xls File on The Client

Tags: maximo

I want to get the location for creating a report file of xls on the client with IBM Maximo. But i couldnt find a way to open a file dialog box. I can use the same object that the user can download a resultset with "Download" link. But i couldnt figure out how to find and use that object, is it possible?

Comment: When you click Download, it is an Excel file that saves to your default Downloads directory. Your question is not worded well and is hard to understand.